# Why is pd.DataFrame.stack so slow compared with numpy.flatten and how to speed it up?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, performance

`pandas.DataFrame.stack` is very slow. On average, pandas.stack costs about 6 times more than `numpy.flatten`. Why is it so slow? Is there any way to speed it up?

```
> df.shape    # dtype = float64
  (2578, 809)
> %timeit df.stack()
  42 ms ± 130 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
> %timeit df.values.flatten()
  7.35 ms ± 17.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: what is `df_old_md`, is it a copy of `df` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Typo. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

`pd.stack` is slower because it operates not only on the blocks of data that are stored as `np.ndarray` within the DataFrame via the [blockmanager](https://dkharazi.github.io/blog/blockmanager), but also needs to deal with indexing. In particular `stack` needs to create a multiindex for the additional index column that is generated.

`pandas` is focused on offering great flexibility in data manipulation while `numpy` offers a low level abstraction over efficient in-memory storage of data.

`pd.DataFrames` have row and column labels, which require additional indexing and labeling operations during the `stack()` process.

Additionally all the labels and indexes also require additional memory, and memory access requires additional time, especially when working with large data sets.

The performance of `pd.stack` is indeed much worse than `np.flatten`:

```
def generate_dataframe(N):
    data = np.random.rand(N, N)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    return df
# List of num_directories values
data_size = [10, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000]
def stack(df):
    return df.stack()
def flatten(df):
    return df.values.flatten()

approaches = [
    stack,
    flatten
]
run_performance_comparison(approaches, data_size,setup=generate_dataframe)
```

[image]

Profiling code:

```
import timeit
import shutil
from pathlib import Path
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from typing import List, Dict, Callable, ContextManager

from contextlib import contextmanager


@contextmanager
def data_provider(data_size, setup=lambda N: N, teardown=lambda: None):
    data = setup(data_size)
    yield data
    teardown()


def run_performance_comparison(approaches: List[Callable], data_size: List[int],
                               setup=lambda N: N, teardown=lambda: None, number_of_repetitions=5, title='N'):
    approach_times: Dict[Callable, List[float]] = {approach: [] for approach in approaches}

    for N in data_size:
        with data_provider(N, setup, teardown) as data:
            for approach in approaches:
                approach_time = timeit.timeit(lambda: approach(data), number=number_of_repetitions)
                approach_times[approach].append(approach_time)

    for approach in approaches:
        plt.plot(data_size, approach_times[approach], label=approach.__name__)

    plt.xlabel(title)
    plt.ylabel('Execution Time (seconds)')
    plt.title('Performance Comparison')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

If you know that you don't need the additional convenience of having a [`pd.MultiIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html) created for you then just stick with the `numpy` implementation. It's efficiently implemented in C or FORTRAN.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to elaborate more on the index manipulation part? I find it a bit difficult to understand why the index manipulation makes it so slow.

Comment: it involves python objects and python code. `PyObject` and python bytecode and interpreter all slow you down. `flatten` is basically just C